# How to use auto generated ID in spring hibernate Model class

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have model class as below in my entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TblKnow")
public class Know {

    @Id 
    @Column(name="IdKnow")
    private Double IdKnow;
```

The ID is autogenerated by database, so i do not need to fill the ID.

But when i put the value id as null i get below exception

```
:ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.melk.spring.model.Know
```

Comment: i also added @GeneratedValue in class but then i get below exception

Comment: Put the exception you get when adding `@GeneratedValue` into to he post - edit it.

Comment: i have changed the Double to double and it is fine now , I wonder when it is double it works but when i use Double which is class it does not work

Comment: Because `Double` is set to null but when you use `double` it is set to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First set your id type to Long, then add `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)`, **don't forget to add a getter & setter for this field.**

```
@Id 
@Column(name="IdKnow")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long IdKnow;
```

Make sure that on your DB the id column is of type BIGINT

Comment: Dear i have done this but still was giving error , i have find the problem , the problem was i was using Double class instead of double variable

Comment: when we use " @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)" the id is generated by Hibernate or it is generate by mysql Table